# Draggable Row with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, draggable

If I have a below type structure, can I make draggable for sorting this 3 rows onto each other?

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
   child: Container(
child: Column(children: <Widget>[
Row(children: <Widget>[Container ( child: Container(....))]) // static

Row(children: <Widget>[Container ( child: Card(....))]) // will be draggable
Row(children: <Widget>[Container ( child: Card(....))]) // will be draggable
Row(children: <Widget>[Container ( child: Card(....))]) // will be draggable

Row(children: <Widget>[Container ( child: Container(....))]) // static
   ]
  )
 )
)
```

Comment: You might want to look into [ReorderableListView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ReorderableListView-class.html)

Comment: It looks suitable, I will check, thanks.